# RearView is not working on nougat using camera2

Tags: android, camera, android-camera2

I am using camera2 library for custom camera. but not able to open camera's rear view in nougat devices.
My Gradle File:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.sitetrack"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    bundle {
        language {
            enableSplit = false
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
        exclude 'META-INF/io.netty.versions.properties'
    }
    // useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
}


dependencies {

    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    //Retrofit
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.6.1"
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.6.1"
    //Glide
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
    //Design
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    //Sugar
    implementation 'com.github.satyan:sugar:1.5'
    //Dimensions
    implementation 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.6'
    //Library
    implementation project(':loaderLibrary')
    //Multidex
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    //GoogleServices
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0'
    //Custom Camera
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-core:1.0.0-alpha01"
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-camera2:1.0.0-alpha01"
    //AWS
    implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-rekognition:2.16.4'
    implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-s3:2.16.4'
    implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-core:2.16.4'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'
}
```

Code for starting camera and changing Lens facing, clicking picture and enable flash.

```
fun startCamera(){
        bindCameraUseCases()
        facingButton.setOnClickListener {
            lensFacing = if (CameraX.LensFacing.FRONT == lensFacing) CameraX.LensFacing.BACK else CameraX.LensFacing.FRONT
            try {
                // Only bind use cases if we can query a camera with this orientation
                CameraX.getCameraWithLensFacing(lensFacing)
                bindCameraUseCases()
            } catch (exc: Exception) {
               exc.printStackTrace()
            }
        }
    }

private fun bindCameraUseCases() { // Make sure that there are no other use cases bound to CameraX
        CameraX.unbindAll()
        val metrics = DisplayMetrics().also { texture.display.getRealMetrics(it) }
        val screenSize = Size(metrics.widthPixels, metrics.heightPixels)
        val screenAspectRatio = Rational(metrics.widthPixels, metrics.heightPixels)

        previewConfig = PreviewConfig.Builder().apply {
            setLensFacing(lensFacing)
            setTargetResolution(screenSize)
            setTargetAspectRatio(screenAspectRatio)
            setTargetRotation(windowManager.defaultDisplay.rotation)
            setTargetRotation(texture.display.rotation)
        }.build()

        val preview = Preview(previewConfig)

        preview.setOnPreviewOutputUpdateListener {
            val parent = texture.parent as ViewGroup
            parent.removeView(texture)
            texture.surfaceTexture = it.surfaceTexture
            parent.addView(texture, 0)
        }

        val imageCaptureConfig = ImageCaptureConfig.Builder()
            .setLensFacing(lensFacing)
            .setFlashMode(FlashMode.ON)
            .build()
        imageCapture = ImageCapture(imageCaptureConfig)

        btn_take_picture.setOnClickListener {
            val dir = File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/SiteTrack/Images")
            if (!dir.exists())
                dir.mkdirs()

            val fileName = System.currentTimeMillis().toString()
            val fileFormat = ".jpg"
            val imageFile = File(dir.getAbsolutePath(), fileName + fileFormat)

            // Store captured image in the temporary file
            imageCapture.takePicture(imageFile, object : ImageCapture.OnImageSavedListener {
                override fun onImageSaved(file: File) {

                    startActivity(Intent(mContext, PreviewActivity::class.java)
                        .putExtra("actualImage", imageFile.absolutePath)
                        .putExtra("compressedImage", compressImage(mContext,Uri.parse(imageFile.absolutePath).toString())))
                    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.enter_from_right, R.anim.exit_to_left)
                    finish()
                }

                override fun onError(useCaseError: ImageCapture.UseCaseError, message: String, cause: Throwable?) {
                    Toast.makeText(mContext,message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                }
            })
        }
        // Apply declared configs to CameraX using the same lifecycle owner
        CameraX.bindToLifecycle(this, preview, imageCapture)
    }
```

This is XML file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <TextureView
        android:id="@+id/texture"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/btn_take_picture"
        android:layout_width="66dp"
        android:layout_height="66dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_15sdp"
        android:src="@drawable/capture_button"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/closeButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_20sdp"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_15sdp"
        android:background="@drawable/circle_frame_background_dark"
        android:padding="@dimen/_8sdp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_close_black_24dp"
        android:tint="@color/white"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/facingButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_15sdp"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_20sdp"
        android:background="@drawable/circle_frame_background_dark"
        android:padding="@dimen/_8sdp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_facing_front"
        android:tint="@color/white"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I have tested this code on Pie, it is working fine but on Nougat(Moto E5), front view is working as per the expectations but Rear View is not even visible

Comment: Changing dependencies to upper version resolved this